# Adding to UIManagedDocument from GCD background queue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch, uimanageddocument

I am creating and adding a number of managed objects to Core Data from a background queue. My understanding was that I could not access the context from the background thread so I was using performBlock to schedule adding to Core Data back onto the same queue that the context was created on. This works just fine ...

My question is during testing I noticed that by removing `[moc performBlock:^{ ... }];` the application still performs as expected (maybe even fractions of a second faster) Do I need the `performBlock`? I would assume I do and its just working (for now :) in a none-threadsafe fashion, I just wanted to check to make sure my understanding is not flawed.

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{ 
    // GET DATA
    // PROCESS DATA
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self managedDocument] managedObjectContext];
    [moc performBlock:^{
          // ADD TO CORE DATA
          [Core createRodInContext:context withDictionary:fuelRodDictionary];
     }];

});
```

**EDIT:** Added implementation for createRodInContext ...

```
+ (Rod *)createRodInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context withDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {

    // CREATE
    Rod *rod = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Rod" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // POPULATE
    [neo setDataCode:[dictionary objectForKey:@"dataCode"]];
    [neo setDataName:[dictionary objectForKey:@"dataName"]];
    [neo setDataReference:[dictionary objectForKey:@"dataReference"]];
    ...
    return rod;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it that performBlock: perform the operations in background thread. If so why are you again using the gcd block on the top of it.

Comment: in the example above the UIDocument (and therefore the managed object context) are created on the main thread. The code above executes on a background thread using dispatch_async. When using Core Data its important to note that the managed object context is not thread safe and can only be accessed on the thread where is was originally created. [moc performBlock:^{}]; executes the specified block on the thread where the moc was created, thus removing any potential threading issues.

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `createRodInContext:`. Within that method lies the key as to why it does or doesnt work

Comment: Added implementation for createRodInContext: its pretty basic really, just a simple insertForEntityName: and then populating a few attributes from the supplied dictionary. Note: I am not at this stage using the returned Rod, I will probably remove it at some later date as I don't think I am going to need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the background thread you *have to use* `[moc performBlock:^{ ... }]` to insert (and populate) a managed object in the main managed object context.

Omitting the `performBlock` means that you use the managed object context (which was created on the main thread) also in a different thread (which is associated with the background queue).

This might work *by chance*, but as soon as the main thread accesses the MOC in the same moment as your background thread, the results are unpredictable because (as you already said), a MOC is not thread-safe.

See also [Concurrency Support for Managed Object Contexts](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1)
in the *Core Data Release Notes for OS X v10.7 and iOS 5.0*:

> **Confinement (NSConfinementConcurrencyType).**
>
> This is the default. You
>   promise that context will not be used by any thread other than the one
>   on which you created it.

But also for the other concurrency types (private queue, main queue), you always have to use `performBlock` (or `performBlockAndWait`) unless your code is already executing on the queue associated with the MOC.

Comment: Thank you Martin, this is what I was thinking. I have been finding it hard to locate any information on this and just wanted to verify that  I was doing things correctly. It seems that I am, and using performBlock: from the background thread is correct. Much appreciated ...